# Equation Of Common Normal

Tags: calculus

How to find equation of common normal between two random non-intersecting conic sections (say a parabola and an ellipse) ? What should be the general approach ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural approach is to take a parametrization $\psi:\theta\to\ldots$ for the normal lines to one conic, then check for which values of the parameter $\psi(\theta)$ is a normal line to the other conic.

Another possible approach is to define a sort of [evolute curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolute) by projecting the origin on the normal lines to a conic, then to intersect such ausiliary curves.

Comment: Truly speaking I didn't get you :-P..your language seems to hi-fi for me!!Anyway thanks..and could just explain with an example the "parameterization" and "evolute" thing :-)